# Problems with repaint()

Tags: java, repaint

Im having some trouble using repaint.The code is supposed to draw a line behind your cursor.

```
package javaapplication6;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Test extends Canvas implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
int x[]=new int[1024];
int y[]=new int[1024];
int size=0;

public void MouseDemo(){
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void paint (Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for (int i=1;i<size;i++) g.drawLine(x[i],y[i],x[i-1],y[i-1]);

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
x[size]=e.getX();
y[size]=e.getY();
size++;

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    y[size]=e.getY();
    x[size]=e.getX();
    size++;
    repaint();
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    size=0;
    y[size]=e.getY();
    x[size]=e.getX();
    repaint();
}

public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e){
    size=0;
    repaint();

}

public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e){}

public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){

}

public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e){}
}

public class JavaApplication6 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

   JFrame win= new JFrame ("Target");
win.setSize(600,500);
win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
win.add(new Test());
win.setVisible(true);

  }}
```

This same code worked at the school computer but when I got home and tried to do another example and it didn't really work so I decided to test this one and it doesn't work either.I would really appreciate some help and an explanation as to why repaint doesn't trigger.

Comment: another example should be posted.

Comment: 1) Don't extend `Canvas`, you're mixing AWT and Swing components, instead extend from `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent(...)` method, not `paint`. 2) Be sure to call `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first line inside `paintComponent`. 3) Place your program on the EDT. 4) Don't call `setSize` but override the `JPanel`'s `getPreferredSize` instead

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is here...

```
public void MouseDemo() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

This is a method, not a constructor, so it will never register your listeners.  Instead, change it to...

```
public MouseDemo() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

Or, based on you actually example code...

```
public Test() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

`java.awt.Canvas` is a heavy weight component, AWT components don't always play nice with Swing, as they have no concept of z-ordering in the way that Swing implements it.

You'd be better off starting with a `JPanel`.

By convention, you should then override the `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting within it, remembering to call `super.paintComponent` first

Because frame borders are inserted into the visible area of the frame, you "useable" area will be less then that specified by `setSize`, instead, you should override the `getPreferredSize` method of the `JPanel` and specify the "usable" area you prefer.  From there, you can `pack` the frame around it.

To avoid any possible issues with threads, you should use `EventQueue.invokeLater` to start you UI in

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    int x[] = new int[1024];
    int y[] = new int[1024];
    int size = 0;

    public Test() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            g.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i - 1], y[i - 1]);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x[size] = e.getX();
        y[size] = e.getY();
        size++;

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        y[size] = e.getY();
        x[size] = e.getX();
        size++;
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Entered");
        size = 0;
        y[size] = e.getY();
        x[size] = e.getX();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        size = 0;
        repaint();

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Test());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.We havent studied JFrame at school so I don't understand some of the things you're saying but for the most part I understood it and now I understand my mistake with the constructor.

Comment: @AntonIvanov Cudos for having a go at something you've not been taught.  Basically in Java, there a 3 primary UI kits, AWT, Swing, JavaFX. Swing is built upon AWT, but there are key differences, the painting mechanism been one of them. You could get started by having a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: @AntonIvanov and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details and ideas